# WP Offload S3 Lite "Please setup GD or ImageMagick" noticed

Tags: plugins

I already had GD library installed. But i see this error in "WP Offload S3 Lite" settings.

> WP Offload S3 Requirement Missing — Looks like you don't have an image manipulation library installed on this server and configured with PHP. You may run into trouble if you try to edit images. Please setup GD or ImageMagick.

I am not able to upload images though images are uploaded in `uploads` folder. i see this after upload is complete

[image]

With this bit of code i have checked if gd is actually installed and it is installed

```
if ( extension_loaded( 'gd' ) && function_exists( 'gd_info' ) ) {
echo "here";
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
```

UPDATE:
I Disabled all plugins but the upload problem is there. But when i switched to default twentyseventen theme upload works and thumbnail is generated.

Comment: can you properly upload when the plugin is disabled and all the thumbnails are generated? if so, contact the author

Comment: If i switched to a default theme upload works, what functionality should be in my theme for upload to work?

Comment: whatever thumbnail it uses should work, or you can incpect the server upload directory and check that maller image are being generated

Comment: hmmm based on your update the problem is with the theme you use

Answer (score 0):

Create a file called phpinfo.php in your DocumentRoot

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

Run it from the command line (php phpinfo.php), check for the gd section.  If the gd section is missing, you didnt install gd.  Now run the same file from the browser (http://domain.com/phpinfo.php) and again check the gd section.  My guess is that the browser gd section will be missing or disabled.  Did you remember to restart Apache httpd or whatever web server you are using after installing gd?